# Basic proof of continuity from definition (With Answer to my own question)

Tags: analysis, continuity

> Prove directly from definition that
>   $$f(x)=3x+25$$ is continuous everywhere.

NOTE: I will be posting a solution to this problem below.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Great , Thank you so much!

Comment: just add in your question that you're writing your own solution to your question below, lest people shall think you're asking something without making some effort and downvote the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Solution,
We need to show that $$\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta >0 s.t |x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$$
Now in other words ; for all epsilon greater than zero, if $|x-c|<\delta$ then $|3x-3c|<\epsilon$. Now to show this we see that $$|3x-3c|=|3(x-c)|\leq3|x-c|$$ So set $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{3}$ we get $$|x-c|<\dfrac{\epsilon}{3} \implies |f(x)-f(c)|=|3x-3c|=|3(x-c)|\leq3|x-c|<3\dfrac{\epsilon}{3}<\epsilon$$ for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$.